# Would your website perform better if you created stylesheets for each screen size, rather than using a feature such as Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

When it comes to creating a responsive WordPress Theme, would you say it to be better practice to simply implement something like a Bootstrap feature or would your website perform better if you created separate stylesheets for the different screen sizes and called them accordingly?

Has anyone experimented with both and able to recall any performance differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick test case shows that Chrome, at least, fetches all the stylesheets no matter what the media query says. This isn't really surprising as users can resize windows. It holds true for `device-width` as well though.

[image: Chrome]

So there are *no savings at all* since all the stylesheets are downloaded.

This comes with the additional code of extra HTTP requests.

There are only negative performance implications.

Comment: Ahhh great.  Thanks for that insight.  I wasn't aware that such testing could be performed but great.

Answer (score -1):

Using  feature such as Bootstrap is very useful because it will give you all style-sheets and java scripts and if you want to use another one then you can add them so it will be very useful to you and it also gives many theams which are very good.